# UiKit Font not working

Tags: html, css, twig, stylesheet, getuikit

I've started using UiKit on a project, included it as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/css/uikit.min.css" />
```

And

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
```

But the uikit font (awesome) is not working. How do I get it to work when including uikit from cdnjs?

Comment: Read the documentation? Check http://getuikit.com/docs/icon.html

Comment: Yes, I've read the docs, but couldn't find why is not working.

Answer (score 1):

To get Icons, You need to add Icon js into your page.

[image]

After your uikir Js add below script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.6.20/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CDN with this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.1/css/uikit.min.css" integrity="sha256-ZRu2uvT+IMWj7ooDbV50SFSrn3Zm3ewBc9s4mye4G58=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

or this (non-minified):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.1/css/uikit.css" integrity="sha256-4PkxSzd/sscScRbjCwUDWp2cQX5CSKb8+TRpBbXULhM=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

if you working on a Local project I suggest using Uikit Src Directly.